# Apply blue frame and icon inside of input box

Tags: jquery, html, css

Based on this code I would like it to add it inside of a input box that contain text. Is it possible to do it?

Thanks!

```js
$(".delete-tag").click(function() {

  $(this).parent().remove();

});
```

```css
.delete-tag {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.delete-tag:hover,
.delete-tag-active {
  background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gcons-2/24/silhouette5-16.png"), none;
  background-size: initial;
}
.delete-tag {
  background-image: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gcons-2/22/airplane1-16.png');
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.post-tag {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #3e6d8e;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #e4edf4;
  border: 1px solid #e4edf4;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: color .15s ease, background .15s ease, border .15s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .15s ease, background .15s ease, border .15s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .15s ease, background .15s ease, border .15s ease;
  -o-transition: color .15s ease, background .15s ease, border .15s ease;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
  padding: .4em .5em;
}
.post-tag:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3e6d8e;
  background-color: #dae6ef;
  border: 1px solid #dae6ef;
  background-color: #DAE6EF;
}
```

```html
<span class="post-tag">
   aasdfas
   <span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span>
</span>



<span class="post-tag">
   basdfasdf
   <span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span>
</span>

<span class="post-tag">
   basdfasdf
   <span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span>
</span>


<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gcons-2/24/laptop1-16.png" />
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can use a `<div contenteditable=true ></div>` instead of an input text box manipulations would be easier

Comment: Can you show me by using code snippet? it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the snippet I have used the tags inside a `div.tags` and added a `p[contenteditable=true]` in a `div` block, Now obviously you will have multiple tags so I have kept one of your tag in one and other two in another one

```js
$(".delete-tag").click(function() {

  $(this).parent().remove();

});
```

```css
.delete-tag {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.delete-tag:hover,
.delete-tag-active {
  background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gcons-2/24/silhouette5-16.png"), none;
  background-size: initial;
}
.delete-tag {
  background-image: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gcons-2/22/airplane1-16.png');
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.post-tag {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #3e6d8e;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #e4edf4;
  border: 1px solid #e4edf4;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: color .15s ease, background .15s ease, border .15s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .15s ease, background .15s ease, border .15s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .15s ease, background .15s ease, border .15s ease;
  -o-transition: color .15s ease, background .15s ease, border .15s ease;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
  padding: .4em .5em;
  float:right;
}
.post-tag:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3e6d8e;
  background-color: #dae6ef;
  border: 1px solid #dae6ef;
  background-color: #DAE6EF;
}



.inputtext{
  float:left;
  border:1px inset #ccc;
  margin:10px;
  width:100%;
  min-height:30px;
}

.inputtext > p.editable{
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  margin:3px;
  width:70%;
  display:inline;
  padding:2px;
}

.tags{float:left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=inputtext>
  <div class=tags>
    <span class="post-tag">
   aasdfas<span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <p class=editable contenteditable=true>Editable Text</p>
</div>


<div class=inputtext>
  <div class=tags>
    <span class="post-tag">
      basdfasdf<span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span>
    </span>

    <span class="post-tag">
   basdfasdf <span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <p class=editable contenteditable=true>Editable Text</p>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gcons-2/24/laptop1-16.png" />
```

This is how it looks to me. I am using safari on a Mac. I checked with Firefox looks ok. Is it something else that you are looking for
[image]

Comment: is it possible to have the button to be on the left side, not right side?

Comment: Sure why not edited the snippet the buttons should be on the left now

Comment: But the data is not inside of input like in the picture. I have updated the content page.

Comment: I have now uploaded the picture. Please inform me if you can't see it.

Comment: @HelloWorld Updated Answer: This is how it looks to me. I am using safari on a Mac. I checked with Firefox looks ok. Is it something else that you are looking for

Comment: I have not expected the result but this time I will take it as a yes. I have uploaded with improved pedagogical ability."http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127963/add-data-with-class-in-input"